# javascript object wont print in console

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have a form with input fields. I am trying to log those fields in the console. The console displays "createUser {firstName: null}"
:
Object

```
<div class="#">
    First Name:<br>
    <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" id="firstName" required> 
    <br>
</div>
<button onclick="user()" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>


function createUser(firstName, lastName, email, userName, password ){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

function user(){
    var user = new createUser(document.getElementById(firstName.text));
    console.log(user);
}

console.log(user);
```

Comment: what is firstName.text ?

Comment: Not your issue, but it's not the greatest idea to have a variable with the same name as your function. In this case it shouldn't matter but if you ever need to recurse over a function, doing this will give you some interesting errors.

Comment: correct this line  var user = new createUser(document.getElementById('firstName').value);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var user = new createUser(document.getElementById('firstName').value);
```

This might help.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your object name same as function name. You need to change one or other. also you need to get the value of input field.

try this

```
var userObj = new createUser(document.getElementById('firstName').value);
console.log(userObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var user = '';
function createUser(firstName, lastName, email, userName, password ){
this.firstName = firstName;
}

function user(){
user = new createUser(document.getElementById(firstName).value);
//the same as accessing the text of <input value="this is my first name.">

console.log(user.firstName);
//log the property firstName of the object user. when you put this.firstName inside a function, it turns that into a property of of the variable you save it as. That means you must call it by using the variable and a "." and the property name ex firstName
}

console.log(user.firstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print all of your input fields value in the console log in the following way:

Considering, you have the following input fields:

```
<div class="divclass">
    First Name:<br>
    <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" id="firstName" required> 
    <br>
    Middle Name:<br>
    <input placeholder="Middle Name" type="text" id="middleName" required> 
    <br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" id="lastName" required> 
    <br>
</div>
<button onclick="user()" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>

function user(){
    var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('#firstName, #middleName, #lastName');
    var inputFieldValues = Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputFields, function(inputField){
         console.log("id: "+inputFields.id + " value: "+inputField.value);
});

}
```